# I need to add css to my rails application in assets pipeline?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app I put my index.html in public folder and it shows  when i go to port 3000 but it doesn't show it with css, I have my css folder and i tried putting it into assets stylesheets but nothing is happing? where do i put my folder with all the css files in it? would i need to change the way my index.html referances my css files?
for now my index.html in public folder references the css files like this `<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">`

i've looked into some tutorials but their a bit complex in understanding

Answer (score 0):

Things put in the public folder won't be processed by the asset pipeline.  This isn't the "rails way" at all, but you can just move your .css to your public folder and call it like you're calling it now.

To gain access to the asset pipeline the quickest way I can think of is to just scaffold generate something, fill in the view with your HTML and then you can call via asset pipeline.  However by default the root route isn't set so you'll have to navigate to localhost:3000/whatever-controller-you-generated-here

I highly recommend reading this guide before you go much further http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you are using rails then why are you using static page like this. If you really want to use this then you have to specify stylesheet like this

```
<link href="/assets/application.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: like what? you said " If you really want to use this then you have to specify stylesheet like this"

Comment: Sorry answered question using mobile phone.